# Agenda con fichero

Tags: php

Quiero crear una pequeña aplicación con dos funciones. Una se llamará guardardatos que recuperará del contenedor GET los datos que hayamos escrito en los campos nombre y apellidos del formulario y los guardará en nuestro fichero.Otra funcion se llamará Verdatos y mostrará los nombres y apellidos guardados en el archivo .txt de los datos guardados con la función guardardatos. Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo? Hasta ahora he intentado con este con este código, pero no sé como definir la funcion verdatos

```
<html>    
<?
if(isset($isset($_POST["ver"]))
{
    echo "<h1> Datos almacenados </h1>";
    ver();
}
else{
    echo "datos guardados";
    guardar();
}

function verdatos(){
    $linea = fgets($texto);
    echo $linea . '<br />';
}

}

function guardar(){
    $nombre = $_POST["varnombre"];
    $apellido = $_POST["varApellido"];
    $texto = fopen( ' datos.txt' + "w");
    fputs($texto,$nombre . "" . $apellido . PHP_EOL);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: por favor revisa [ask] y también realiza [tour] la comunidad funciona apoyándote a resolver dudas concretas de programación; es decir muestranos lo que haz inteantado y que fallos haz tenido

Comment: te sugiero leer esto: ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157720/how-do-i-save-form-data-in-html-to-a-txt-file

Comment: y este: https://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete

Comment: Lo primero es que la pregunta no es clara. ¿Quieres ver los datos antes de guardarlos en el fichero (supongo)? Entonces sólo tienes que hacer un `echo` de los datos del POST. Luego, llamas a una función `ver()`, pero esa función como tal no existe. Y también tienes una cierre `}`  de más en el código. Por favor explica mejor lo que quieres y se te podrá entonces ayudar.